# Dúvida sobre highcharts e php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, highcharts, gráfico

Para estilização de uma página web, costumo usar os gráficos do highcharts com informações de um banco de dados mysql via php. Para quem não é familiarizado com o highcharts, eis abaixo um código simples de exemplo.

```
Highcharts.chart('minhadiv', {
chart: {
    type: 'bar'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Categoria 1', 'Categoria 2', 'Categoria 3'],
},
series: [{
    name: 'Informação',
    data: [1, 2, 3]

}]
});
```

Esse código me retorna um gráfico assim: 
[image: Gráfico Highcharts]

Sempre faço a conexão php com o mysql dentro do campo `data`, obtendo sucesso.
Abaixo segue o exemplo de uma conexão sql que já utilizei anteriormente:

```
data: [<?php
      $mysqli = new mysqli('servidor', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');
      $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT minhacoluna from minhatabela");
                     ?>
                    <?php while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {?>
                      <?php echo $result["minhacoluna"]?>,

                    <?php } ?>],
```

O problema é que agora eu precisava fazer essa conexão sql tanto no campo `data` quanto no campo `categories`, visto que as categorias podem mudar conforme meu banco de dados. Ao tentar colocar um código php como o acima que normalmente uso, não obtive resultado. Como proceder neste caso?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim para mostrar um gráfico com as categorias conforme está no banco de dados.

Registros no Banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código em php para ser alimentado o gráfico:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('servidor', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');


// Aqui você pode fazer um select alimentando normal uma váriavel com as categorias a ser exibida
$categories = array();


$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT nome from categorias");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $categories[] = $result['nome'];
}

// Select para pegar os dados da tabela
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT coluna, valor from grafico");

$valores = array();

// while dos registros alimentando um array
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $valores[$result['coluna']][] = floatval($result['valor']);
}

// aqui irá ser colocado a váriavel que foi alimentada por array no while acima
// para deixar no padrão que o highcharts reconhece
foreach($valores as $key => $value)
{
    $series[] = array('name' => utf8_encode($key), 'data' => array_values($value));
}
```

Código em js do highcharts:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Chart title'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: <?=json_encode($categories); ?> // Transforma array em json para mostrar as categorias
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: <?=json_encode($series); ?> // Transforma array em json para mostrar as informações do gráfico
});
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas as suas categorias continuam as que inseriu manualmente... (Categoria 1, Categoria 2 e Categoria 3). Quando tentei pegar direto do banco de dados não funcionou.

Comment: Alterei o código para pegar as categorias do banco de dados... Caso não funcione, poste o erro para conseguirmos te ajudar precisamente..